# ¿Cómo asignar turno a un registro libre dependiendo de la fecha y hora en que se registre? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy desarrollando un sistema el cual le asigna un turno al usuario en cuanto completa un formulario, **el formulario cuenta con módulos, cada módulo puede tener 250 turnos cada 30 min en un horario de 8:00 hrs a 16:00 hrs.**

En total por día son aprox. 4000 turnos por módulo los que se pueden generar.

No tengo experiencia en generar turnos, lo que empecé a construir fue una tabla llamada Turnos la cual contiene los campos `ID,FECHA_CITA(HORA Y FECHA), ID_REGISTRO, ID_MODULO,NO_TURNO` en la cual ya inserte los turnos por modulo por fecha los cuales en el campo `ID_REGISTRO` esta vacío, ya que es la llave foránea de la tabla `REGISTRO`, la cual al momento de revisar la disponibilidad de turnos me tome el primer registro disponible y le haga un `UPDATE` asociando `el ID_REGISTRO`.

A lo que me lleva a la siguiente duda realizo el registro el día *08/03/2021*, pero hay citas disponibles hasta el día *15/03/2021*

¿Cómo puedo asignarle un turno a un registro y revisar si esta disponible y que cumpla con el rango de horas es decir si realizo un registro después de las 4 de la tarde como puedo brincar al siguiente turno disponible inmediato del día siguiente?

Lo que tengo es este *query* para ver la disponibilidad

```
            DECLARE @HORA_IN TIME,@HORA_FIN TIME,@FECHA_IN DATE,@FECHA_FIN DATE,@ID_MODULO INT,@TOTAL_TURNOS INT,@FECHA_TURNO DATETIME,@FECHA_ACTUAL DATETIME=GETDATE()
            SET @FECHA_IN='2021-03-15'
            SET @FECHA_FIN='2021-03-31'
            SET @ID_MODULO=1
            WHILE (@FECHA_IN<@FECHA_FIN)
            BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 @FECHA_TURNO=T.FECHA_CITA,@TOTAL_TURNOS=COUNT(*),@HORA_FIN= '16:00' HORA_LIMITE FROM TURNOS T 
            WHERE CAST( T.FECHA_CITA AS DATE)=@FECHA_IN AND ID_MODULO=@ID_MODULO AND ID_REGISTRO IS  NULL
            GROUP BY T.FECHA_CITA
            ORDER BY T.FECHA_CITA ASC

            IF(@TOTAL_TURNOS<=27 AND @FECHA_ACTUAL<= @HORA_FIN)
            BEGIN
            SET @FECHA_IN=DATEADD(DAY,50,@FECHA_IN)
            SELECT CONCAT('TURNOS DISPONIBLES ',@TOTAL_TURNOS,' EN LA FECHA ',@FECHA_TURNO)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
            SET @FECHA_IN=DATEADD(DAY,1,@FECHA_IN)
            END
```

Estos son mis registros de prueba, por el momento agregué 3 turnos por cada 30 min por módulo por día, pero la idea es realizar 250 turnos por 30 min por módulo por día **(Los que esta en `Null` son los turnos disponibles).**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé como asignarles el turno a un registro disponible dependiendo de la fecha y hora en que haga el registro.

**Actualización ya tengo la forma de asignar turnos solo me falta como brincar la fecha en caso de que se haga un registro después de las 4 en ese día para que no lo vaya a guardar**

```
                DECLARE @HORA_IN TIME,@HORA_FIN TIME,@FECHA_IN DATE,@FECHA_FIN DATE,@ID_TURNO INT
            DECLARE @MODULO INT=1
            SET @FECHA_IN='2021-03-15'
            SET @FECHA_FIN='2021-03-31'

            WHILE (@FECHA_IN<=@FECHA_FIN) --RECORRO LAS FECHAS
            BEGIN
            set @HORA_IN='08:00'
            set @HORA_FIN='12:00'
            WHILE (@HORA_IN<=@HORA_FIN)--RECORRO LAS HORAS
            BEGIN
            SELECT @ID_TURNO= ID FROM TURNOS WHERE ID_MODULO=@MODULO AND CAST(FECHA_CITA AS DATE)=@FECHA_IN AND CAST(FECHA_CITA AS TIME)=@HORA_IN AND ID_REGISTRO IS NULL --ME RETORNA EL PRIMERO DISPONIBLE
            IF(@ID_TURNO IS NOT NULL OR @ID_TURNO>0)
            BEGIN
            --PRINT CONCAT('REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO: ',@ID_TURNO,' HORA: ',@HORA_IN,' FECHA 1: ',@FECHA_IN)
            UPDATE TURNOS SET ID_REGISTRO=2 WHERE ID=@ID_TURNO AND ID_REGISTRO IS NULL AND ID_MODULO=@MODULO --ACTUALIZO EL REGISTRO DISPONIBLE

            IF(@@ROWCOUNT>0) -- SI SE ACTUALIZO ALTERO VALORES PARA QUE SALGA DEL LOOP. SI NO, CONTINUA RECORRIENDO
            BEGIN
            PRINT CONCAT('REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO: ',@ID_TURNO,' HORA: ',@HORA_IN,' FECHA: ',@FECHA_IN)
            --INCREMENTO LOS VALORES DE HORAS Y DIAS PARA QUE NO CONTINUE EN EL LOOP
            SET @HORA_IN=DATEADD(HOUR,100,@HORA_IN)
            SET @FECHA_IN=DATEADD(DAY,100,@FECHA_IN)
            --PRINT CONCAT('REGISTROS ACTUALIZADOS: ',@@ROWCOUNT)
            END
            END
            SET @HORA_IN=DATEADD(MINUTE,30,@HORA_IN)
            END --HORA
            SET @FECHA_IN=DATEADD(DAY,1,@FECHA_IN)
            END--FECHA
```